When changing a kendoswitch programmatically the label does not change
I have a KendoSwitch set to "On". I run the code below and it's checked status does go to false but the label does not change. I would expect it to say "Off". I cannot work out why as when i run code to check its status it is set as false after running the below code:
var thatSwitch = $("#" + 'KendoDemo').data("kendoSwitch");

thatSwitch.check(false);


You need to use the toggle method on the switch. Like so:
var thatSwitch = $("#" + 'KendoDemo').data("kendoSwitch");
thatSwitch.toggle();

The documentation:
https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/switch/api
or
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/switch/methods/toggle

This is correct. Oddly my switch was set as "True" but for some reason was not showing as true
